# Given 3 slopes of 3 lines in which all three wont intersect at the same point. How can we determine whether a triangle can be formed or not?

Tags: geometry

For example
The angles made by the $3$ lines are $50$, $90$, $20$ with $x$ axis.
How can we prove mathematically that they can form a triangle?

Actually I'm writing a program that takes n slopes as input and prints the no. of triangles that can be formed with them. so, in a mathematical way I have asked this question.

Comment: That's not true in general, if all of the three lines meet at a point they don't form a triangle.

Comment: So long as the three slopes differ and the lines don't all meet in a point, then a triangle must be formed.  Simple.

Comment: This is not true. the so-called triangle inequality must be fulfilled!

Comment: Can you say what is that triangle inequality?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner: I would really like to see how you involve the triangle inequality here.

Answer (score 0):

This generally depends on the relative position of the lines but if we force two of them intersect at origin the 3rd one shouldn't be concurrent with the two others i.e. if two lines with angles $20$ and $50$ intersect at origin the other one with angle being 90 should be of form$$x=a\quad,\quad a\ne 0$$Another way to saying that is: if the slopes are distinct i.e. all three angles are in the interval $\left[-\dfrac{\pi}{2},\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)$ and distinct, knowing that this lines aren't concurrent they always form a triangle.

Comment: Please do not take co ordinates into consideration. Please try to make it mathematically prooved only with slopes

Comment: Alright! I added some other information. Hope it works...

Answer (score 0):

The information about the angles tells us that none of the lines is parallel to another.

It could be the case that the three lines intersect at a single point, and in that case there is no triangle.

If the three lines do not intersect at a point, call the lines $L_1,L_2,L_3$. Let $A$ be the intersection of $L_1$ and $L_2$, and $B$ the intersection of $L_1$ and $L_3$. We cannot have $A=B$ by our assumption. Since $L_2$ and $L_3$ are not parallel, they intersect at a point $C$. We cannot have $C=A$ or $C=B$ because again we would have a triple intersection. So $ABC$ is a triangle formed by the three lines.

Comment: thankyou for helping me.